# Is there an option that I can set my default sim number to my edittext when my cursor moves to edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am setting up an app that will get an otp verification on my and then verifying the number I will get into my app. The edittext should ask me which number would you like to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String n = tm.getLine1Number();
```

then add permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```